# Add specific results into a vector automatically

Tags: r, vector, match

I have written a code using if functions and the results of each if loop (212 of them) give a result of "n" or the sum of lags from an acf graph. I want to find the minimum value and then recall the corresponding commands within that if-loop

Here is an example of the first two if-loops im using:

```
orderWA1<-c(0,0,0)
orderWS1<-c(0,0,0)
ArimaW1 <- Arima(N, order= orderWA1, seasonal=list(order=orderWS1), method="ML")
if(aslog=="y"){Arimafit<-exp(fitted(ArimaW1))}else{Arimafit<-fitted(ArimaW1)}
nnn<-c(N)
arimab<-c(Arimafit)
fullres<-nnn-arimab
v<-acf(fullres,plot=FALSE)
w<-pacf(fullres,plot=FALSE)
if(v$acf[2]>0.4|v$acf[2]<(-0.4)|v$acf[3]>0.4|v$acf[3]<(-0.4)|v$acf[4]>0.4|v$acf[4]<(-0.4)|v$acf[5]>0.4|v$acf[5]<(-0.4)|v$acf[6]>0.4|v$acf[6]<(-0.4)|v$acf[7]>0.4|v$acf[7]<(-0.4)|w$acf[1]>0.4|w$acf[1]<(-0.4)|w$acf[2]>0.4|w$acf[2]<(-0.4)|w$acf[3]>0.4|w$acf[3]<(-0.4)|w$acf[4]>0.4|w$acf[4]<(-0.4)|w$acf[5]>0.4|w$acf[5]<(-0.4)|w$acf[6]>0.4|w$acf[6]<(-0.4))
  a01<-"n" else
  {a01<-sum(abs(v$acf[2:7]))
   b01<-sum(abs(w$acf[1:6]))}
orderWA2<-c(0,0,0)
orderWS2<-c(0,0,1)
ArimaW1 <- Arima(N, order= orderWA2, seasonal=list(order=orderWS2), method="ML")
if(aslog=="y"){Arimafit<-exp(fitted(ArimaW1))}else{Arimafit<-fitted(ArimaW1)}
nnn<-c(N)
arimab<-c(Arimafit)
fullres<-nnn-arimab
v<-acf(fullres,plot=FALSE)
w<-pacf(fullres,plot=FALSE)
if(v$acf[2]>0.4|v$acf[2]<(-0.4)|v$acf[3]>0.4|v$acf[3]<(-0.4)|v$acf[4]>0.4|v$acf[4]<(-0.4)|v$acf[5]>0.4|v$acf[5]<(-0.4)|v$acf[6]>0.4|v$acf[6]<(-0.4)|v$acf[7]>0.4|v$acf[7]<(-0.4)|w$acf[1]>0.4|w$acf[1]<(-0.4)|w$acf[2]>0.4|w$acf[2]<(-0.4)|w$acf[3]>0.4|w$acf[3]<(-0.4)|w$acf[4]>0.4|w$acf[4]<(-0.4)|w$acf[5]>0.4|w$acf[5]<(-0.4)|w$acf[6]>0.4|w$acf[6]<(-0.4))
  a02<-"n" else
  {a02<-sum(abs(v$acf[2:7]))
   b02<-sum(abs(w$acf[1:6]))}
```

i want to be able to get find the names of all the things not giving "n"

so i want a vector that looks like

```
a01 a02 a03 a04 a06 a08 etc
```

where it just chooses the ones that are a number

Comment: the variable names, otherwise it would just be a vector of "y"'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
l1 <- mget(ls(pattern="^a\\d+"))
library(gtools)
mixedsort(names(unlist(l1[sapply(l1, `==`, "y")])))
# [1] "a1"  "a2"  "a4"  "a5"  "a6"  "a8"  "a11" "a12" "a13" "a15"
```

Comment: how does the `pattern` work? i would like to be able to use it for other variable names such as a000000, a100000, a010000 ... a111111 would it work with the same method?

Comment: @Summer Gleek It should work because the pattern is for any variable that starts with letter `a` followed by numbers.

Comment: I have come across a problem, perhaps you can help me? i have edited the question to show my problem

Comment: @Summer Gleek Could you post it as a different question as this may confuse others.

Comment: unfortunatly my account has been blocked from asking new questions because i dont get a good enough response from people, im only able to edit questions

Comment: oh yes. i didnt think of that! thankyou ill do that now. and put your answer back as accepted answer